# how to encode bool variables in solidity

Tags: solidity, encoding, abiencoderv2

i am trying to encode a bool variable as callback data (bytes). i am doing this by using `abi.encodePacked` for reduced space and cost and a custom decoding function.

The issue is that after decoding, the returned variable is always true no matter what the packed encoded value is.

here is the code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/** 
 * @title Ballot
 * @dev Implements voting process along with vote delegation
 */
contract TEST {
   
   function encodeBytes() public pure returns (bytes memory){
       
      bool x = false;
       return abi.encodePacked(x);
   }
   
   
   function decode(bytes memory data) public pure returns ( bool b) {
        assembly {
            b := mload(
                add(
                    data,
                    8
                )
            )

        }
    }


    function decodeAndReturn() public returns (bool){
        bytes memory packed = encodeBytes();
        return decode(packed);
    }
}
```

calling `decodeAndReturn` would return true even if the encoded variable is explicitly set to false.
is the issue with my decoding function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `decode` function, you are not loading the `data` correctly. First, you need to determine the length of the `data`. This can be done using `mload(data)` which loads the length of `data`, the length is located at the first 32 bytes.

After the first 32 bytes that define the length of `data`, you can load the `data` using `mload(add(data, 0x20))`. Just to clarify, `0x20` is equivalent to 32 bytes.

So, your code should be the following:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/** 
 * @title Ballot
 * @dev Implements voting process along with vote delegation
 */
contract TEST {
   
   function encodeBytes() public pure returns (bytes memory){
      bool x = false;
      return abi.encodePacked(x);
   }
   
   
   function decode(bytes memory data) public pure returns (bool b){
        assembly {
            // Load the length of data (first 32 bytes)
            let len := mload(data)
            // Load the data after 32 bytes, so add 0x20
            b := mload(add(data, 0x20))
        }
    }


    function decodeAndReturn() public pure returns (bool){
        bytes memory packed = encodeBytes();
        return decode(packed);
    }
}
```